# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, outofmemoryerror

Пытаюсь достать все веб-файлы из папки в List с помощью рекурсии. Когда маленькое количество файлов, то всё работает, а ошибка возникает, когда начинаю парсить папку с 80 тыс. файлов. Память Eclipse выделяет до 1024.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReaderHtml {
    List<Path> files = new ArrayList<Path>();

    public List<Path> listFiles(File path){
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+\\.(html|htm|php|HTML|HTM|PHP)$");  
         Matcher m; 
        for (int i=0;i<path.listFiles().length;i++) {

            File file = path.listFiles()[i];
            if (file.isDirectory()){                
                files.addAll(listFiles(file));
            }
            else {   
                m = p.matcher(file.getName());
                if (m.matches()){
                    Path b = new Path();
                    b.file = file;
                    b.mark=0;
                    files.add(b);
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
    public class Path{
        File file;
        int mark;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в методе `listFiles` в случае, когда встреченный файл является папкой, добавляете результат рекурсивного вызова в список `files`, но при этом вызываемая функция и возвращает *этот же* список `files` (т.к. `files` является полем класса), т.е. вы постоянно удваиваете `files`.

Чтобы исправить, достаточно сделать `List<Path> files` локальной переменной метода вместо поля класса.

---

Ну и пара замечаний по оптимизации:

- замените повторяющийся вызов `path.listFiles()` на переменную перед началом цикла;
- сделайте `Pattern p` константой уровня класса (`static final`).

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло "пара замечаний по оптимизации" ))

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас рекурсия слишком глубокая и отжирает всю память. Могу предложить следующие варианты:

1. избавиться от рекурсии, и сделать цикл
2. увеличить размер стека вызова метода, добавив ключ -Xss<размер памяти в килобайтах, мегабайтах или гигабайтах>[k|m|G]
3. максимально избавиться от создания объектов в цикле и методе